# How to install torch and Detectron2 framework on Azure App Service using requirement.txt?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, flask, pytorch

I have build a flask app for image segmentation using pretrained model from Detectron2,locally I can run the app without any issue/errors, I am trying to deploy same app on Azure App Service, the problems seems to be installing Detectron2 framework, detectron2 require torch python package to get installed correctly, is there any workaround to install both torch and detectron using requirement.txt

this is the content of requiremnet.txt

```
firebase==3.0.1
firebase-admin==5.0.3
Flask==2.0.2
imutils==0.5.4
matplotlib==3.3.4
numpy==1.21.6
opencv-python==4.5.3.56
pandas==1.1.5
Pillow==8.4.0
scikit-image==0.17.2
scikit-learn==0.21.3
webcolors==1.11.1
Werkzeug==2.0.2
gspread==5.4.0
oauth2client==4.1.3
opencv-contrib-python==4.5.3.56
tensorflow
torch

# Detectron detectron2
git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git
```

and here is the error I am getting from Azure Logs

```
  python: 3.7.15
Warning: An outdated version of python was detected (3.7.15). Consider updating.\nVersions supported by Oryx: https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx

Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.7.15/bin/python3.7
Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
Removing existing manifest file
Python Virtual Environment: antenv
Creating virtual environment...
Activating virtual environment...
Running pip install...
[05:40:09+0000] Collecting git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
[05:40:09+0000]   Cloning https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-3_w8g61y
  Running command git clone --quiet https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git /tmp/pip-req-build-3_w8g61y
[05:40:12+0000]   Resolved https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git to commit 1523b3e9929a06d798871eb9afc4c9f770743baf
[05:40:12+0000]   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
[05:40:12+0000]   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-3_w8g61y/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
          import torch
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

I have already tried using different python version, please suggest some workaround or any corrections I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

- here I have work around where you manually install some package and then use the `requirements.txt` file. The reason for this is the module not found error.
- Before we begin we should  first install the `gcc` , `g++` and `git` this is done using the following command

```
apt-get install <Package name>
```

- Now we can install the python packages (I have created `venv` before we start installing) Independently we can install two i.e. `torch` & `pycocotools`
- Now we can run the `requirements.txt` with all the remaining packages.
  My `requirments.txt`:

```
firebase==3.0.1
firebase-admin==5.0.3
Flask==2.0.2
imutils==0.5.4
matplotlib==3.3.4
numpy==1.21.6
  
pandas==1.5.3
Pillow==9.4.0
scikit-image==0.19.3
scikit-learn==1.2.1
webcolors== 1.12
Werkzeug==2.2.3
gspread==5.7.2
oauth2client==4.1.3
opencv-contrib-python==4.7.0.68
tensorflow
opencv-python==4.7.0.68

# Detectron detectron2
git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git
```

Output should like this alfter install all the packages:

[image]